# Script to wait till user enters valid id

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm trying to write a script that looks up if a user is valid and if they are currently logged on. 
I can't wrap my head around getting it to wait till the user enters a valid id.

```
while read one
do

if id "$one" >/dev/null 2>1;

then
Matrix=$(who -u |grep -q "$one" || test && echo "logged on" || echo "not logged on")

fullname=$(grep "$one" /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f5 | sort -k 2 | tr ",,:" " " | awk '{print $2,$1}')

echo "$fullname is $Matrix"

else
echo "user doesnt exist"

fi
break
done
echo "maybe"
```

Comment: What are you asking? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: What will stop the user from editing the script, or just going around it?

Answer (score 1):

The `read` utility will *wait* until data has been entered, so

```
read username
```

will not return until a user has entered something that the shell then stores as `$username`.

If you by "wait" mean "loop until a valid username has been entered", then you could do something like

```
while true; do
    read -p 'Enter username: ' username
    if id "$username" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf 'Username "%s" is valid\n' "$username"
        break
    fi
    printf 'Username "%s" is not valid\n' "$username"
    echo 'Try again...'
done
```

This goes into an infinite loop that will only exit when a valid username has been entered by the user.  The validity is checked with the `id` utility, which is what your code seems to be using as well.  If the utility exits without an error, the loop is escaped through `break`.

After this loop, you know that you have a valid username in `$username`.

To test whether the user is logged on, you may use `who` as you've done (here with slight modifications):

```
if who | grep -q "^$username\>"; then
    printf 'User "%s" is logged on\n' "$username"
else
    printf 'User "%s" is not logged on\n' "$username"
fi
```

The usernames are found in the first column of the output of `who`.  We therefore anchor the username to the start of the line with `^`.  We also make sure to match a word boundary at the end of the username with `\>` (so that we don't detect user `arthur` when we're actually looking for `art`).

Instead of `who` we could have the `users` utility.

To get the full name of a user, you would do

```
name=$( getent passwd "$username" | cut -d : -f 5 | cut -d , -f 1 )
```

The `getent` utility is used to get, amongst other things, the password database or an entry from it.  Here, we use it to get the password database entry for the particular user we're interested in.  We then parse out the full name from the GECOS field's first comma-delimited value.

Note that we could have used `getent` as the utility to test valid usernames with (as it returns a non-zero exit status if you use an invalid username with it), and that way had gotten the full name of the user in the process without having to do another query afterwards.

Taken all together:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p 'Enter username: ' username
    if id "$username" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf 'Username "%s" is valid\n' "$username"
        break
    fi
    printf 'Username "%s" is not valid\n' "$username"
    echo 'Try again...'
done

name=$( getent passwd "$username" | cut -d : -f 5 | cut -d , -f 1 )
printf 'Full name of "%s" is %s\n' "$username" "$name"

if who | grep -q "^$username"; then
    printf '%s is logged on\n' "$name"
else
    printf '%s is not logged on\n' "$name"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preset the result on error to enter in a loop, do the job inside the loop and during the next iteration ask for the real result.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ok=1
while [ $ok -gt 0 ]; do
    read one
    < your check of $one >
    ok=$?
done
```